# Azure function/durable funciton container disposed error (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-runtime

We are using Azure function v~3 and nodejs runtime v~14/~12
recently we have been experiencing lots of container disposed error

**The error Message /  stack :**
**The host is disposed and cannot be used. Disposed object: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedResolver' Container is disposed and should not be used: Container is disposed.
You may include Dispose stack-trace into the message via:
container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())**

Need help in identifying root cause of this issue or
Need assistance resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Muhamed

Comment: Did you created a support ticket via the Azure Portal?

Comment: No Not via Azure Portal but you can I raised in forum link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/351397/azure-functiondurable-funciton-container-disposed.html